# Are iPhone Push Notifications sent over HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I want to implement Push Notifications on iOS. Can anyone tell me if the push notifications can be sent over HTTP or HTTPS? Or are both possible?

Comment: does that answer your question? if so please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Apple push notification is done over TCP using port 2195.
On the other hand, HTTP uses port 80 and https uses port 443.

Hope that helps.